# what is the difference between REST API and normal API in grails?

Tags: rest, api, grails, grails3

and which is better REST API or normal API for web based application?

do I need to apply the plugin first to use REST API in grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be best off learning the traits of all kinds of HTTP APIs:
http://algermissen.io/classification_of_http_apis.html

Questions like "which is better" are highly subjective and not really a good fit for this website.